# How can i control Datatable Colvis on Page load?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable table-colvis datatable" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column1</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column2</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column3</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column4</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column5</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column6</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Column7</th>
  <th style="background-color:#235671; color:white; font-size:12px;">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','****','');
mysql_select_db('****');
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Table_name');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo '<tr>
    <td style="font-size:12px;"><input type="text" value="'.$row["col1"].'" class="form-control"/></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;"><input type="text" value="'.$row["col2"].'"/></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$row["col3"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$row["col4"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$row["col5"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$row["col6"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$row["col7"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px; width:7%;"><i class="icon-upload-alt"</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-pencil"</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-trash"</i></td>
    </tr>';
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here i have used table-colvis to show/hide column of the DataTable. But i need to hide some columns while page load itself. So i have used the following code

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ 
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
        } );
```

Its not working. Again i used the following.. But unfortunately, thats also not working.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    colVis: {
        exclude: [ 0 ]
    }
} );
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: Yep.. The Error is DataTable Warning: (table id = 'example' : Cannot reinitialize table. To retrieve the datatables object in this table, pass no arguments or see the documentation for bretrieve or bdestroy

Comment: it means you have already reinitialised the instance for the selected node. in your case it is '#example'. plz check that have initialised .dataTable() twice? refer Diagnosis section here : https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: I have checked.. I couldnt find that '#example' anywhere in my page except single time on initializing the datatable.. But still not working

Comment: can you provide me jsfiddle demo with static html <tbody> ?